# How to do reverse proxy on waitress server for Python Flask Application

Tags: python, virtualhost, waitress

I am a newbie in web deployment and I have a flask application which is being hosted at 0.0.0.0:5070. Now I want to do the reverse proxy and be able to direct a certain hostname (bound to server IP) to this port. I have tried the Waitress documentation but seems to be of no help. Any guidance in this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using uwsgi is recommended. Its full fledged app server which sits behind your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what @Debendra mentioned is correct.  For production workload, it is recommended to use `uwsgi` as your application server.

From there, you'll need to use a web server to act as your reverse proxy.  Please refer the following documents:

[What is uWSGI?](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[How To Serve Flask Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Read the above to become familiar with the components and submit another question if you want a follow up.